# How do i call the defined functions by RequireJS in html?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

It's about main.js i guess, but I've tried all the examples I found online and they just didn't work.

I have currently: three modules (one.js, two.js, three.js), main.js, index.html and some references files like require.js

`one.js`:

```
define("one",['./two', './three'], function(two, three) {
  var one = 1;
  return {
    value: function(e){
      return one;
    }
  } 
});
```

`two.js`:

```
define("two",['./one', './three'], function(one, three) {
  var two = 2;
  return {
    value: function(){
      return two;
    }
  }    
});
```

`main.js`:

```
require(["one", "two", "three"], function (one, two, three) {

});
```

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    // the function from two.js having the same name as another in one.js needs to be called here.
    <body onload="value();">  
        <h1>My App</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you are trying to do it. Your call:

```
require(["one", "two", "three"], function (one, two, three) { });
```

does load your modules but then their values become available through the parameters of your callback. **Nothing is exported to the global space.** But for `<body onload="value();">` to work, `value` must be in the global space.

Another problem is that RequireJS is asynchronous. So even if you rewrote your code to deliberately have module `two` leak its `value` to the global space, **the code would not work reliably.** In general you cannot know when your `require` call will complete relative to when `body`'s `onload` will be fired.

You could work around the problem by having "glue code" load what you need. Set `<body onload="onBodyLoaded()">` and have a `script` before `body` that has:

```
function onBodyLoaded() {
    require(["two"], function (two) {
        two.value();
    });
}
```

If this were my code, I'd actually not use the `onload` attribute but would instead have a `script` after body with something like:

```
(function () {
    document.body.addEventListener("load", function onBodyLoaded() {
        require(["two"], function (two) {
            two.value();
        });
    });
}());
```

Or I'd use the [`domReady` plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/domReady). It is not quite the same as listening to the `load` event on `body` but it may be "good enough".

Answer (score -1):

Calling `onload` function is the same concept as `require` callback invocking in `main.js`. You just need to call function inside `require`'s callback:

```
require(["one", "two", "three"], function (one, two, three) {
  one.value();
});
```

All `require`'s callback parameters are references to functions created by `define`. There won't be any conflict between same methods inside them.